# CSS units inconsistency

Tags: css, google-chrome

Assuming that `100%` = `16px` = `1em` = `1` (applies to unitless `line-height`) I think that `162.5%` = `26px` = `1.625em` = `1.625`.

When I set `line-height` to `1.625` or `1.625em` or `26px` it's exactly alike in Chrome but when I set it to `162.5%` it's not exactly alike (in Firefox it's always OK).

Does anyone how why does this happen? I've really tried to find some mistake and I couldn't. I came across this table which has inconsistent values (e.g. they say `160%` is `26px` instead of `162.5%` but why?): http://www.getallfix.com/2011/11/convert-empxpt-and-in-css/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tr9Nr/1/ (must be opened in Chrome or IE11, in Firefox it's always OK)

Comment: Well, Chrome ca render `line-height` in integers when using pixels as unit. I don't know why it behaves like this but you can clearly see line-height only increases by 1px at min no matter what unit you are using. I can't seem to find the related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct: `100% = 16px = 1em = 1`

The inconsistency you see is in how webkit browsers like chrome render decimal percentage values. In your case webkit appears to floor the percentage line-height instead of rounding it, so 162.5% will always render as 162%; see [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y38gS/).

I can't really say that this is a bug since sub-pixel rendering standards aren't really well defined...  this is just how webkit does it.

The example chart you posted seems to be rounding the pixel values.

You can take solace in the fact that your layouts will never be off by more than a couple of pixels. Besides, cross-browser pixel-perfect layouts are merely a utopian ideal to dream about. :-/

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question! Your explanation on how it rounds the values answers everything.

Comment: There are cases where webkit's handling of sub-pixel rendering is a bit odd and can actually have a fairly noticeable effect on readability when applied to large blocks of text. Take for example a line-height of 1.35714286 has a calculated value of 18.999998px. Chrome rounds this to 18px. If the font size is something like 14px, that can have a pretty significant impact on a block of text. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLaq1yk6/)